Why does "Fall Again" by Michael Jackson/Robin Thicke/Walter Afanasieff sound kind of sad?
It's a romantic ballad, with lyrics like "I need you around for every day to start", but, to me at least, there is a sad undertone to it.
Is it just because he sings a lot of the song in a falsetto (falsetto's overtones are apparently similar to the overtones of crying), or is there something about the composition of the song itself that gives it this feeling?




Hate to say this, but to some folk, songs in minor keys will imbue or suggest the feeling of sadness - particularly the slower ones. Sad, but true!! And this song, although it moves in and out of that minor key, at least starts in it. Can't imagine it would sound as melancholy were it in a major key.

Interesting, thanks!

It’s a lament. Hundreds of years ago, a descending bass line and chord progression like on this song became associated with sad lyrics. Now we have inherited that cultural association so lament chord progressions generally come across on the sadder side.

Can't decide whether All My Loving comes into that category; it has that descending bass line, and the chords aren't far off.

@Tim I’m hearing a jazz style walking bass line in “All My Loving”. Even though it starts with a chromatic descent, the rhythm and note values give fast descending walking bass a different feel from a lament. To me they are two different things. To make a lament sound right it’s usually one bass note per chord.

Interesting, thanks. Is the entire song a lament, or just the opening section that has that descending bassline?
